# Reason for unexpected results of SJF scheduling?

Tags: c, operating-system

I wrote the code to implement SJF scheduling but it is not printing the waiting time and turnaround time correctly. It is printing a large no. I expected the normal output after calculating the turnaround time and burst time.

```
/** PREEMPTIVE SHORTEST JOB FIRST SCHEDULING */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 10

/** global variables */
int burst_time[MAX];
typedef struct
{
    int arrival_time;
    int burst_time;
    int turnaround_time;
    int wait_time;
} Process;

void main(){
    Process p[MAX];
    int i,n;
    printf("\n  SHORTEST JOB FIRST");
    printf("\n  ------------------");
    printf("\n\n  Enter no of processes? ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\n\t\t ARRIVAL TIME      BURST TIME");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("\n  Process %d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d %d",&p[i].arrival_time,&p[i].burst_time);
    }

    p[0].turnaround_time=p[0].burst_time+p[0].wait_time;
    /** calculate waiting time and turnaround time of each process */
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        p[i].wait_time=p[i].arrival_time-p[i-1].turnaround_time;
        p[i].turnaround_time=p[i].burst_time+p[i].wait_time;
    }

    /** Print details of each process */
        printf("\n  +------------+--------------+--------------+------------+-----------------+");
        printf("\n  | PROCESS ID | ARRIVAL TIME | WAITING TIME | BURST TIME | TURNAROUND TIME |");
        printf("\n  +------------+--------------+--------------+------------+-----------------+");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            printf("\n  |     %2d    |      %2d     |      %2d     |     %2d    |       %2d       |",i+1,p[i].arrival_time,
               p[i].wait_time,p[i].burst_time,p[i].turnaround_time);
        }
        printf("\n  +------------+--------------+--------------+------------+-----------------+");
}
```

Comment: Please show the output you get and the one you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Here you init index 0 of the array:

```
p[0].turnaround_time=p[0].burst_time+p[0].wait_time;
```

Immediatly afterwards you overwrite index 0 with values calculated based on values which were read via undefined behaviour, by accessing the illegal index -1; in the very first iteration of the loop.

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        p[i].wait_time=p[i].arrival_time-p[i-1].turnaround_time;
        /* ... */
}
```

That might explain your results, but in fact, once undefined behaviour is involved, all bets are off. Read up on "nasal demons".

This part of possibly more problems in your code can probably be fixed by starting your loop on `for(i=1; /* ... */`.